# How can I get 2 different data types from 1 ng-model in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I got fine code in mean stack, but I want one another feature in it. Namely I want to get more elements from my database, while I am selecting options.

My database is NoSql:

Tir2 :id, price, xin, yin, xout, yout...etc.

This is my code:

index.js

```
   <select size="10" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="response.data" multiple>
   <option ng-repeat="tir in tir2" ng-value="[tir.mapsUrl]">{{tir.id}}</option></select>

   ng-src="{{response.data[0]}}"
```

Controller.js

```
   $http.get('/tir2').then(function(response){
    $scope.tir2 = response.data;

    var googleMapsUlr = "origin={0} destination={1}";

    angular.forEach($scope.tir2, function(element, key) {

        element.mapsUrl = googleMapsUlr.replace("{0}", element.xout + "," + element.yout).replace("{1}", element.xin + "," + element.yin);
    });
```

This works perfectly for me, but I need to add some more information about selected id. I came up with something like this above.

Controller.js

```
    var info ="{0},{1},{2},{3}";
    ........
    ........
    element.info2 = info.replace("{0}", element.dateout).replace("{1}", element.datein).replace("{2}", element.price).replace("{3}", element.kmeters);
```

And now I don't know how can I separately show these two elements (`info2`, `mapsUrl`) by one click on select options.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use the ng-repeat in select, you can use ng-option directive.

Your model data structure is not clear but if you want to post everything say a complete user record on selection then use like this:

```
ng-model ='modelname'
ng-options="user as user.name for user  in users track by user.id"
```

When you will select an item in dropdown it will put complete user record in your model.

[For more detail see this link](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1196/angularjs-dropdown-select-value-text-multiple-values-with-demo)